How (or why) to infer schema for write-only Spark 3 TableProvider?
I'm trying to implement a TableProvider in Spark 3 to write to a custom format. I'm not interested in reading, so it looks something like:
class MySpecialDataSource extends TableProvider  {
  override def inferSchema(caseInsensitiveStringMap: CaseInsensitiveStringMap): StructType = {
    // caseInsensitiveStringMap contains path -> /tmp/path/to/write/to
    ???
  }

  override def getTable(structType: StructType, transforms: Array[Transform], map: util.Map[String, String]): Table = {
    new MySpecialTable(structType)
  }
}

class MySpecialTable(val schema: StructType) extends Table with SupportsWrite {
  ???
}

and I try to use it like this:
df.write
    .format("my.package.MySpecialDataSource")
    .mode("append")
    .save("/tmp/path/to/write/to")

Before anything else, inferSchema is called with just the path I passed to save. If I return an empty schema, later I get this error (my dataframe has one column named acolumn):
Cannot write to 'atable', too many data columns:
Table columns: .
Data columns: 'acolumn'.

How can I "infer" the schema if it's the first time I write? Is there maybe a different abstraction from TableProvider that I should implement?

Perhaps you can override default implementation of supportsExternalMetadata() in your extension. Per the interface doc, returning true should disable schema inference altogether. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider.html#supportsExternalMetadata--

You're right, I tried that and it no longer calls inferSchema. Thank you!

Great, thanks for the update!

The answer from @mazaneicha 's comment:
Override supportsExternalMetadata() to return true.
